# Prove that if $A^2=I$ for matrix $A_{3\times 3}$, then $A$ has a trace of either $-1$ or $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've came across this interesting problem that I've been struggling with for some time now. It asks, as the title suggests, to show that involutory $(A^2=I$ or $A=A^{-1})$ $3\times 3$ matrix has a trace of either $1$ or $-1$, when $A\ne I$ and $A \ne -I$.

I've tried doing the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}, A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now this becomes very tedious and it didn't seem like it could get me anywhere.

After this, from the fact that $tr{A}$ is equal to sum of its eigenalues, I thought of finding them using $\det({A-\lambda I})=0$, once again this didn't led me to anything.

Maybe the problem could be me missing out on something obvious in these calculations, but I couldn't see anything. How could I actually solve this, possibly in less messy manner? Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: But what can the eigenvalues be? Use the definition, not the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't know. Were you thinking of the same idea as the one shown in the answer from Simple?

Comment: I might be missing something, but for the 3x3 identity matrix we do have that $I^2=I$ yet the trace is 3, that statement seems to be false. Are you referring to the determinant of such A matrix?

Comment: @jDAQ as I've written in the post $A \ne I$ or $A \ne -I$.

Comment: @jDAQ sorry, not "or" it should of been "and", just so there's no confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$Av=\lambda\,v\rightarrow A^2v=\lambda^2v$ and $Iv=\lambda^2v$. So, $\lambda=\pm1$.

Comment: But this doesn't necessarily imply that the trace is equal to $-1$ or $1$, in fact couldn't it also be $3$ or $-3$?

Comment: @bb_823 the only way to have eigenvalues be $\pm 1$ and have the trace be $3$, is for the matrix to be similar to $I$ (i.e all eigenvalues are $+1$), which means it is equal to $I$. But you excluded $I$ from the discussion. Similar story with trace of $-3$. The only thing to be elaborated on is the existence of eigenvalues (i.e you have to do some finessing with the underlying field).

Comment: @peek-a-boo ok, thank you.

Comment: @peek-a-boo No. E.g. we have $A^2=I$, $A\ne\pm I$but $\operatorname{tr}(A)=3$ when $A=\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1}$ over $GF(2)$. The current answer is incomplete.

Comment: @user1551  but in that field $3=1$ so it doesn’t seem to be a counterexample. But I’ll admit I was ignoring finite fields (actually even thinking of only rationals or reals or complex) when I wrote my comment because I hadn’t fully thought it through.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I am not saying that the $A$ in my previous comment is a counterexample to the statement that the OP wants to prove. What I am saying is that this answer is incomplete. While it has correctly identified the possible eigenvalues of $A$, it hasn't addressed the case where $A$ has a triple eigenvalue.

Comment: @user1551 do you, by triple eigenvalue mean, eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity of $3$. Wouldn't then the trace be $3$, too.

Comment: @bb_823 Yes, but that actually can only happen over a field of characteristic $2$, and so $3=1=-1$.